# Get thumbnail image of website via link with smart filter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, filter, thumbnails

I have an issue.

I have a url of the article and would like to take the title, description and thumbnail of that article.

Currently I have solved the title, description, and thumbnail images I only get the ads?

If you can, please help me get a smart filter

My solution: using PHP to get the entire contents of the site, then use jQuery as follows:

```
var elements = $(html_content);
img = $(found).find('img').first();
```

I welcome all the better solution

Thanks

Sorry, my english is bad, hope you understand!

Comment: Can we see the website and the img you want to get ?

Comment: This url: http://vtc.vn/dau-bep-an-bun-cha-cung-obama-toi-doi-doi-vi-den-viet-nam.311.620730.htm
Img src i get: https://gyazo.com/2af9cfcef929226fb2e6a0c4c68c40b7

Answer (score 0):

You could use `file_get_contents($url)`, should work.

Notice that `$url` has to contain the entire url, include de `http://` or  `https://`

PD:Your english is ok ;)